# How to make the background color cover the entire "block" when hovering over it

Tags: css, hover

I'm learning CSS and I'm trying to copycat a simple nav bar from this [website](http://davidhellmann.com/).
I want a black background to appear when hovering over an item so I did this:

```
nav a:hover {
background: black;
}
```

but the background is only covering the text. I want to it to cover the entire element like in the original site.

And here's the anchor tags CSS if you need it:

```
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 2em;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coded the same as on your example website, hope it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/yL7yj4xL/1/ (You have to remove `padding-right` and replace it for just `padding`)

Comment: Interesting :D
But changing padding-right to padding results in the items getting out of position.

Comment: Then put you full code here to help me helping you please. @Sam

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have the nav elements in a `<ul><li></li></ul>` structure.

in that case, change the `nav a:hover` to `nav li:hover`
EDIT:
Made this fiddle off of your pen: https://jsfiddle.net/djgsgqp5/

Your `nav` `ul` and `li` elements were getting no height. If you hover on those elements in the devtools youl see they only have a width.

The style in the fiddle is much more stable hopefully does what you need.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Now nothing happens when I hover!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle of an example and post it here so that i can take a look at the markup?